# Cross Correlation of two sequences with different length using convolution in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, convolution, cross-correlation

Assume that we have two simple sequences with different lengths:

```
x = rand(3,1);
y = rand(2,1);
```

I calculated the cross correlation between them and plot it such below:

```
r_1 = xcorr(x,(y));

tx = 1:length(x);
ty = 1:length(y);
tr = ceil(-(length(x)+length(y)-1)/2) :  floor((length(x)+length(y)-1)/2);

subplot(2,2,1); stem(tr,r_1); title('XC');
```

I wanted to calculate the cross correlation using convolution and show that it's result is equal to the result when using xcorr(). But when I implemented it like this:

```
r_2 = conv(x,fliplr(y));

tx = 1:length(x);
ty = 1:length(y);
tr = ceil(-(length(x)+length(y)-1)/2) :  floor((length(x)+length(y)-1)/2);

subplot(2,2,1); stem(tr,r_2); title('XC');
```

the length of r_1 and r_2 are different and 
I got this **error:**

> Error using stem (line 43)
>   X must be same length as Y.

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three issues in your code:

1. You are applying `fliplr` to `y`, but `y` is a column vector, so **you are not really flipping it**. You should apply [`flipud`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html); or [`flip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) if you want it to work for any vector in general.
2. From the documentation of [`xcorr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xcorr.html):

   > `C = xcorr(A,B)` [...] > If `A`and `B` are of different length, *the shortest one is zero-padded*.

   So, to make the result of `conv` equal to that of `xcorr` you need to **zero-pad** the shorter vector.

   In the general case, for column vectors `x` and `y` you can use `[x; zeros(numel(y)-numel(x),1)]` instead of `x` and `[y; zeros(numel(x)-numel(y),1)]` instead of `y`. This will extend the shorter vector and leave the other as is. Note that this works because, according to the documentation of [`zeros`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html),

   > `zeros(M,N,P,...)` [...] The size inputs `M`, `N`, and `P`... should be nonnegative integers. *Negative integers are treated as `0`*.
3. The correlation applies a **complex conjugate to the second input**. You should do the same with convolution. In your example it doesn't matter because inputs are real, but it should be done in general.

Combining the three items above:

```
r_1 = xcorr(x, y);
r_2 = conv([x; zeros(numel(y)-numel(x),1)], conj(flip([y; zeros(numel(x)-numel(y),1)])));
```

should give the same result.

**Example**:

```
x = [3.1; -4.3; 5.6];
y = [2.6; -8.4];
```

give

```
r_1 =
   0.000000000000004
 -26.040000000000006
  44.180000000000000
 -58.219999999999999
  14.559999999999999
r_2 =
                   0
 -26.040000000000003
  44.180000000000000
 -58.219999999999999
  14.559999999999999
```

which are the same up to numerical precision errors.